# Guice injection not working in web application

Tags: guice

I am trying to get Guice to work in a web application deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4
When I try to step through the Guice code, I notice that the binding is happening. However, when I try to inject the bound object, I always get null. The following are the code changes I have done to enable Guice -

1) **web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.univeris.guice.GuiceConfig</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

2) **GuiceConfig**

```
@Singleton
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
            new ServletModule() {
                @Override
                protected void configureServlets() {
                    serve("/uif/*").with(UIFInitializeServlet.class);
                    serve("/upm/*").with(IDPServlet.class, ImmutableMap.of("instance-name","upm"));
                    serve("/uiw/*").with(IDPServlet.class, ImmutableMap.of("instance-name","uiw"));
                }
            },
            new MainModule()
    );

    return injector;
  }
}
```

3) **MainModule**

```
public class MainModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new BankAccountModule());
        install(new CoreModule());
    }
}
```

4) **BankAccountModule**

```
public class BankAccountModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
 bind(BankAccountProvider.class).toProvider(BankAccountGuiceProvider.class);      
 bind(BankAccountService.class).toProvider(BankAccountServiceProvider.class);
    }
}
```

5) **BankAccountGuiceProvider**

```
public class BankAccountGuiceProvider implements Provider<BankAccountProvider> {
    @Override
    public BankAccountProvider get() {
        return ProviderLocator.locateProvider(BankAccountProvider.class);
    }
}
```

6) **BankAccountServiceProvider**

```
public class BankAccountServiceProvider implements Provider<BankAccountService> {

    @Override
    public BankAccountService get() {
        BankAccountService bankAccountService = ServiceLocator.locateService(BankAccountService.class);
        return bankAccountService;
    }
}
```

7) **BankAccountServiceUVS**

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(ServiceInterceptor.class)
public class BankAccountServiceUVS implements BankAccountService {

    @Inject
    private BankAccountProvider _bankAccountProvider;

    @Override
    public BankAccountCollection getAllBankAccounts(final Integer entityId, final String entityType) {
        BankAccountCollection retVal = _bankAccountProvider.getAllBankAccounts(entityId, 
        return PojoHelper.cloneObject(retVal);
    }
}
```

The **_bankAccountProvider** is always injected as null. I have been pouring through several forums for several days to no avail. Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: how are you instantiating BankAccountService or BankAccountServiceUVS?

Comment: Share the code for BankAccountServiceProvider.

Comment: I have added in the code for BankAccountServiceProvider. Also note that BankAccountService and BankAccountProvider are EJBs that are looked up using JNDI using ServiceLocator class.

Answer (score 0):

Guice assumes that if you write a Provider for an object, you have injected that object already, and that it doesn't need to do so itself.

On the [Injections page in the Guice Wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections), Guice lists ways to access injected objects from the graph, but in most cases Guice assumes that it is creating those objects itself (aside from the Automatic Injections section at the bottom, which applies to `toInstance` and `toProvider` bindings to already-created instances).

Your Provider uses `ServiceLocator.locateService` to find and create your BankAccountService, which does not trigger any of Guice's injections. Therefore, your BankAccountService will not have its `@Inject`-annotated members injected.

---

In your position, I would proceed with caution: You have made BankAccountServiceUVS into *a class that evidently expects to be created using a dependency injection framework*. Your ServiceLocator and Guice Injector have some overlapping responsibilities, and if any non-Guice clients were to inject your BankAccountServiceUVS, they would see your @Inject field as `null`. I'd proceed with one of these options instead, with my most-preferred options first:

- Remove BankAccountServiceUVS from JNDI and use Guice to create and inject it with your interceptors as needed. This appropriately reflects that BankAccountServiceUVS won't work without Guice, Spring, or some other @Inject-aware framework.
- Modify BankAccountService to contain an initialization method, like `void init(BankAccountProvider accountProvider)`. This means that BankAccountService consumers have an additional requirement to call that method, but allows BankAccountService to work regardless of the implementation or dependency injection framework. In order to get the BankAccountProvider, you can add an @Inject field to your `BankAccountServiceProvider` class; unlike BankAccountService, BankAccountServiceProvider is created by Guice and [gets automatic access to @Inject fields](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings).
- Modify BankAccountServiceProvider to inject an Injector, which is a [default binding in Guice](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html). In the call to `get`, after getting your BankAccountService from JNDI, call [`Injector.injectMembers(Object)`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers-java.lang.Object-) on it. This will populate all `@Inject` fields and call all `@Inject` methods, by reflectively inspecting the object instance. Note that this is the most unintuitive and dangerous of these three methods, because Guice inspects the dynamic type of the object (BankAccountServiceUVS) where other DI frameworks like Dagger will only inspect the static type of the object (BankAccountService) and won't find anything @Inject-annotated on the interface. It also effectively requires BankAccountServiceUVS to be constructed with a DI-framework like Guice, as a call to `new BankAccountServiceUVS()` will succeed but interactions with `_bankAccountProvider` will fail if Guice doesn't inject the object.